# Run a script with trigger when i modify another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, eventtrigger

i Would like to run a script in a spreadsheet (called A) when i do modifications in a spreadsheet (called B).
Is it possible? considering that the script in the spreadsheet A takes info from the spreadsheet B.

Thank you guysss

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I tested using this script:

```
function test() {
  var rangeToEdit = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEET A ID").getActiveSheet().getRange(4, 1);
  rangeToEdit.setValue("I edited sheet B") 
}
```

This script is on Sheet B! I set a trigger to execute it "on edit". Every time you edit Sheet B it will write "I edited sheet B" on sheet A row 4, column 1.

Comment: Thank you Eduardo,  and is it possible to run a script in sheet A ONLY when i see I Editted sheet B ( or something else)?, the important thing is that i run a script only when i see a modification in some specific cells of sheet A ( modification in one specific cell is fine). The tipical trigger EDIT runs when it see modifications in the entire spreadsheet, i would like to run only if some cells are modified. Thank youu

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but you can have an onEdit script that checks if that cell was modified (or has some specified value) and then execute some logic if it was...